# How to get a border gradient on button to transition on hover without flashing?

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue getting the gradient border of a button to transition smoothly on hover. Right now, there is a weird flash when you hover off of the button. Any ideas on how to fix that?

```css
.button {
  border-radius: 9999px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  width: 300px;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  height: 3rem;
  display: table;
  letter-spacing: 0.125rem;
}

.button-text {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.button:hover {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(#ffffff, #ffffff) padding-box,
    linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(151,215,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,169,224,1) 50%, rgba(51,0,114,1) 100%) border-box;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button">
  <div class="button-text">
    Button
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

move the background to the main element (not the hover state)

```css
.button {
  border-radius: 9999px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(#ffffff, #ffffff) padding-box,
    linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(151,215,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,169,224,1) 50%, rgba(51,0,114,1) 100%) border-box;
  width: 300px;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  height: 3rem;
  display: table;
  letter-spacing: 0.125rem;
}

.button-text {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.button:hover {
  border: 2px solid #0000;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button">
  <div class="button-text">
    Button
  </div>
</a>
```